# Running perf on a single thread in a multi-core system

Tags: linux, perf

Running `perf` for the first time to profile some code at a function level:

I've a multi-core system, but I would like a profile a single thread which is pinned to a core. `4269` is the PID, and `dp-ipc12` is the thread I'm interested in:

```
root@svc:~# ps -T -p 4269 | grep ipc
4269    4454 ?        00:02:45 dp-ipc12
```

The thread ID is 4454. I'm running `perf` as below:

```
perf record -F 99 -p 4269 -t 4454 -g -a
```

When I see the the `perf report`, I see only only line for this thread:

```
 0.07%  dp-ipc12       datapathd                      [.] unixctl_server_wait
```

What am I missing here?

Appreciate your time and response.

Comment: Are you sure the result you see is not correct?
For posterity: If you specify the thread ID, you do not also need to specify the process ID.